# .htaccess Sub Sub-Directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I would like to know if it's possible to point my domain to a directory which is two folders in from the root.

My hosting company doesn't allow me to change this so I need to do this with an .htaccess file.

This is my structure...

```
public_html
    .htaccess    <-- Here will be my .htaccess file.
    folder
        folder
        folder
        folder
        public   <-- My desired folder.
```

All requests must point to the public folder 2 levels downwhere the frameworks .htaccess file exists and index.php file exists.

I hope this all makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **RewriteBase**

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /folder/public/
 RewriteRule . /folder/public/index.php [L]
```